# storing an image in a database

Tags: java, mysql

I used a code that allows me to see the result of my treatment graphically. I want to store the graph in my MySql database (in WampServer). How can I do this?

Here is what I have tried:

```
if (jCheckBox1.isSelected()) {
    try {
        con = getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/base_rapport_tt", "root", "");
        Statement statement = con.createStatement(rs.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, rs.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        String sql1 = "Select last_updated_by,(count(id_incident) )*100/(Select count(id_incident) from incident where Status like 'Closed' and open_time between '" + jTextField1.getText() + "' and '" + jTextField2.getText() + "')from incident  where  Status like 'Closed'and open_time between '" + jTextField1.getText() + "' and '" + jTextField2.getText() + "' group by last_updated_by";
        rs1 = statement.executeQuery(sql1);
        DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();
        while (rs1.next()) {
            pieDataset.setValue(rs1.getString("last_updated_by"), rs1.getDouble(2));
        }
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("Taux résolution par personne", pieDataset, true, true, false);
        PiePlot3D piePlot3d = (PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot();
        piePlot3d.setLabelGenerator(new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0}={1}"));
        fenetre fen1 = new fenetre();
        pnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        fen1.setContentPane(pnl);
        fen1.setVisible(true);
        setSize(700, 700);
        ChartPanel cPanel1 = new ChartPanel(chart);
        pnl.add(cPanel1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also convert image in base64 and save it as string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.base64-encode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, yes, you can store arbitrary binary data in MySQL using [BLOB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) type. An example schema:

```
CREATE TABLE images (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    description VARCHAR(40),
    data BLOB
);
```

It appears you're using Java on the backend, if so you should check out the [Using Large Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/blob.html) tutorial.

However, there are reasons you may not want to do this; see [Should I use MySQL blob field type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1717264/151845) for some discussion on that.