# Is it okay to store small videos(less than 5 seconds) as blobs in mysql?

Tags: mysql, video, blob

I am given to know that video blobs should not be stored in MySQL. But what if the video is very small with a maximum length of 5 seconds. Is it okay to store small videos(less than 5 seconds) as blobs in mysql?

Answer (score 2):

It's okay to store media data as a `BLOB`, regardless of length, as long as the content isn't larger than the maximum size for the data type (64KB for `BLOB`, 16MB for `MEDIUMBLOB`, 4GB for `LONGBLOB`).

Many software developers will insist that media belongs in files, not in the database, but there are [good reasons to store data in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1717568/20860) too.

This is basically a matter of opinion. The best solution for your project may be different from their project.